# Can't set cache control public to .js, .css and image files

Tags: .htaccess

I used Chrome to audit my site and I discovered .js and .css files weren't being cached though I had set up my .htaccess file to do so.

I removed everything from my site's root htaccess file except the code below and I'm still getting the message "The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible" in Chrome indicating my main external .js and .css files aren't being cached. These files and images represent like 90% of the total download size so not being able to cache them is driving me crazy.

This is currently the code of my .htaccess file. Having it exactly like this still doens't cache anything.

```
# Disable Etags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Cache-Control "public"

<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi|html?)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresActive Off
</FilesMatch>

# Enable Compresion
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

You can see this code not working at http://lujanventas.com

How can I set cache control public to .css, .js and image files?

Comment: "You can see this code not working" :D ... Anyway, is it DEFLATEing properly, at least?

Comment: Also, why did you disable ETags?

Comment: It seems to be deflating properly, just not caching at all. About ETags I read it was good for performance. Was it a bad idea?

Comment: Something I read on askapache.com **By removing the ETag header, you disable caches and browsers from being able to validate files, so they are forced to rely on your Cache-Control and Expires header.**

Comment: Removing the ETag is advised by Yahoo. It's also useless to use both last-modified and etag at the same time. As for the original question. Try clearing the browsers cache. I've had chrome use the cached files to do the audit, and those older files didn't have the expires headers yet.

Comment: My chrome loads almost everything from cache. Are you sure you aren't behind a proxy that's mangling your caches or something like that? EDIT: Seems like you've got one little problem there. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment of writing, your running server generates headers that way for JavaScript:

```
Expires: access plus 1 day
```

This is incorrect, it should have been replaced by effective date and time. So it explains no browser is able to cache the resource properly.

According to [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html), there is no reason why it does not work.

Is there any hidden character in your configuration that prevents Apache2 to parse the line properly ? Try to delete the line `ExpiresDefault` line and type it again from scratch in an reliable text editor.

If still failing, where does your Apache2 version/binary comes from ?

Comment: @Liso22 Thanks for the bounty. And I am curious to know what was exactly wrong with your Apache2 configuration file... how have you fixed it ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert with cache controls and expire headers, but I always use this code and it always works (I'm not quite sure if that's what you are looking for but I post it anyway, see if it works for you or not) :

```
#################
# CACHE HEADERS #
#################
## BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</IfModule>
## END Expire headers
#################
# CACHE CONTROL #
#################
## BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|gz|ttf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, public"
    </filesMatch>
    # Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
## END Cache-Control Headers
########
# ETAG #
########
## KILL THEM ETAGS
Header unset ETag
FileETag none
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# 1 Week expire
<filesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf|css|js)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

#No caching
<filesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi|html)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
```

I believe this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file modify:

```
Header set Cache-Control "public"
```

to look like

```
Header set Cache-Control "public max-age=31536000"
```

So your files get cached for at least a year (max-age is in seconds).

Why? I loaded your page twice and i saw the request sends a `max-age=0`

Also, check out this [page](http://www.webscalingblog.com/performance/caching-http-headers-cache-control-max-age.html), it gives some insights in the mod_expires module.